# Getting latlong in popup on mouse click over linear feature using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I´ve created a Geojson layer of linear features using the option "onEachFeature" to binding a popup wich shows some data for each feature.
This is the code that is working right for this purpose:

```
function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.id = feature.properties.num,
    layer.bindPopup(
        "<div class='row'>"+
            "<b>Orden de trabajo (</b>" + feature.properties.estado +"<b>)</b></br>"+
            "</br>"+
            "<b>Identificador: </b>" + feature.properties.num +"</br>" +
            "<b>Fecha ini.: </b>" + feature.properties.f_ini +"</br>" +
            "<b>Fecha est. fin: </b>" + feature.properties.f_estimada+"</br>"+
        "</div>"

    )
};

var l_encurso = L.geoJson(<%- ordenesl %>, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.estado == "En curso";
    },
    style: function(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 5,
            color: 'green'
        };
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
```

Now, i would like to get the coordinates (lat long) of the mouse position when i click over the linear feature and show them also in the poup.

Can you give me any idea, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert dynamic data into a popup you want to pass a function into `bindPopup` that returns the rendered popup content at the time of popup creation. In this rendering function, you can use a stored value for the latlng to display the location of the clicked coordinate. To obtain the clicked coordinate you want to use leaflet's `click` event, which contains information on the coordinate that was clicked.

Edit: Because you want to use feature data in the render function you actually need to use a function factory (a function that returns a function), so you can specialize each function to use the feature-specific data.

```
// variable that will store the coordinate
var clickedLatLng = {lat: null, lng: null}; 

// function that creates the popup content
function createPopupContent(values) {
    return function () {
        return "....other data like " + values.data1 + " and " + values.data2 + "..." + clickedLatLng.lat + ', ' + clickedLatLng.lng;
    }
}

// function that is called when line is clicked
function onLineClick(e) { // e is a leaflet Event object
    clickedLatLng = e.latlng;
}

function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
    layer.id = feature.properties.num;
    layer.bindPopup(createPopupContent(feature));
    layer.on('click', onLineClick)
};

var l_encurso = L.geoJson(<%- ordenesl %>, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.estado == "En curso";
    },
    style: function(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 5,
            color: 'green'
        };
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed idea. It really works for me.